# SQL is incomplete while searching with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have the following relationship in Rails: Campaign -has-many- Promise(s)

And I have the following Ruby code to return verbose list of campaigns with promises count:

```
def campaigns
  results = Campaign
    .where(user_id: current_user.id)
    .left_outer_joins(:promises)
    .select('campaigns.*', 'COUNT(DISTINCT promises.id) AS promises_count')
    .group('campaigns.id')
    .ransack(params[:q])
    .result(distinct: true)

  render json: {
    results: results.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page]),
    total_results: results.count(:id)
  }
end
```

Everything works fine, unless I try to sort by `promises_count`. Ransack (or something else?) generates the following SQL for Postgres:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  campaigns.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT promises.id) AS promises_count
FROM "campaigns"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "promises"
    ON "promises"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "promises" "promises_campaigns"
    ON "promises_campaigns"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id"
WHERE "campaigns"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY campaigns.id;
```

It works, but there is no `ORDER BY` for some reason. When I sort by other properties, it works fine. I think Ransack is missing something, and handles `promises_count` different way because it's generated property and not real one.

It's possible to sort in Postgres, for example, manual query with added `ORDER BY` works:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  campaigns.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT promises.id) AS promises_count
FROM "campaigns"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "promises"
    ON "promises"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "promises" "promises_campaigns"
    ON "promises_campaigns"."campaign_id" = "campaigns"."id"
WHERE "campaigns"."user_id" = 1
GROUP BY campaigns.id
ORDER BY promises_count desc;
```

How do I make Ransack work? I tried different combinations of queries without too much luck.

Comment: I have no idea about `Ransack`, but would not old good `order('COUNT(DISTINCT promises.id)' => desc)` or `order(promises_count: desc)` work?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin well, sort string is provided from client, I believe Ransack sanitize these params somehow. It's good and bad :)

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I am pretty sure query is about `WHERE` and has nothing to do with the ordering.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin yes. Ransack is type of tool that adds functionality at the top of your activerecord chain. So it adds some ordering, when it's provided by client. In the case above ordering works, but only for fields other than `promises_count`. You don't see any ORDER BY statements, but if you change ordering to `created_at` from the client, query will be generated with ORDER BY. Exception is only for `promises_count`.